# Bootstrap popover element access

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display placeholder in the input text box in **IE9**, the following code is working fine but it is not working in the Bootstrap popover text box.

```
<script>
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
    });

    // Placeholder for IE
    $(function() {
        if(!$.support.placeholder) { 

            var active = document.activeElement;
            $(':text, textarea, input[type="password"]').focus(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            });
            $(':text, textarea, input[type="password"],input[type="password"]').blur();
            $(active).focus();
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
            });
        }  

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you have missed a quotes `()` after `function` for `//Placeholder for IE`

Comment: @Pavlo i missed here,but add in the code ,its not working..thanks for your comment.

Comment: @rightPath It would be helpful if you could provide an online demo or a JSFiddle.